# Show that if $K$ is compact and nonempty, then $\sup K$ and $\inf K$ both exist and are elements of $K$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Show that if $K$ is compact and nonempty, then $\sup K$ and $\inf K$ both exist and are elements of $K$.

If $K$ is compact, then by definition it is closed and bounded, and every sequence in $K$ has a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in $K$. $K$ is also nonempty. Let $s = \sup K$ and $t = \inf K$. Since $K$ is bounded, it has an upper and lower bound, which can be defined by $s$ and $t$, respectively. If a set is closed, it includes its bounds in the set, so $s,t \in  K$.

Is the proof I wrote correct?

Comment: Compact sets need not be closed in non-Hausdorff spaces, and non-metrizable spaces do not even have the concept of boundedness. I suggest you review the definition of compactness.

Comment: Assuming that $K$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, it is true that if $K$ is compact, then it is closed and bounded. To show that $\sup K\in K$, what can we say about a sequence in $K$ which converges to $\sup K$?

Comment: Also be careful when you say "if a set is closed, it includes its bounds in the set." A singleton is closed but admits many upper/lower bounds that don't belong to the singleton. Your claim is true if you replace "bound" by "least upper bound" or "greatest lower bound."

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but it depends on what you take for granted. If you've already shown that the following are true:

- A subset of the real numbers is compact iff it is closed and bounded (Heine-Borel theorem);
- Every bounded subset of the real numbers has a supremum and an infimum (least-upper-bound property);
- The supremum and infimum of a subset belong to its closure;

Then the claim immediately follows: the supremum and infimum of a compact subset exist by boundedness, and belong to the subset by closure.